# Can one Shave the hair on his neck during Sefira?

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, parts-of-the-body, shaving, beard

During sfira (and the 3 weeks), I find that my neck gets extremely uncomfortable and itchy from not shaving (and not very presentable). Is it permissible to "clean up" or even out my beard by shaving my neck? Is hair on the neck considered part of the beard? And is only the beard assur to shave during sfira, or is any hair?

Comment: I doubt greatly it's a problem. I think even an actual mourner has leniencies for the reasons you mention. And (at least) with regard to sefira, I believe the Chatam Sofer held one should shave every erev shabbos.

Comment: In fact, I think it's quite widespread that working men who would not be presentable otherwise shve during these periods.

Comment: Minhagim are not incumbent on a mitztaer.

Comment: I'm not sure whether its permissible or not...I just noticed wearing a hooded jacket even without putting the hooded part over the head seems to block the neck line however. Maybe not ideal solution in all situations but at least its something.

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](http://www.bknw.org/uploads/5/9/9/5/5995719/shaving_during_sefira.pdf) . My inference from this is that considering that there was a debate regarding shaving in general, plus even for those opinions that prohibit shaving, there's a debate if that means only the beard, there are leniencies to rely upon regarding shaving your neck.

As there is no consensus, from what I can tell, CYLOR.

If you DO shave your neck, don't stick it out for others too much ;-)